# How to retrieve EditText multiline text as it is android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-canvas

I do some drawing on canvas.
I have a multiple line edittext.
How to show the text on canvas as multiple line?

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />



 final TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.input);
....
  @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                text = textview.getText().toString();
...//Here I store the input from edittext in the string.
```

If the input is multiline, how to store this as multiline in the string?

Thanks much in advance!!!

Comment: Can you post any example..?

Comment: Are you adding edittext programmatically on the Draw method

Comment: I have added my example

Comment: no, I have a corresponding layout, after that I inflate that edittext.

Comment: say I write  Toast.makeText(mContext, mText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); when |I have entered a multiple line text. I obtain just a string consisting from 1 line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `RichEditText` instead of an `EditText` might solve your problem.

Look at this [Project on GitHub](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit)

You might have to use this in your xml file instead of plain `EditText`

```
<com.commonsware.cwac.richedit.RichEditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/editor"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="top|left"
  android:inputType="textMultiLine">

  <requestFocus/>

</com.commonsware.cwac.richedit.RichEditText>
```